# What is prestige in Far Cry 5?

Tags: far-cry-5

I was looking at items in the shop to purchase with in game currency and found that several items have a prestige logo over the top. What is prestige in this game? Is this after completing the main story or is there a prestige system in online multiplayer?

Answer (score 3):

From [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/farcry/comments/870ojm/far_cry_5_prestige_system/), we can say, that there is no prestige system itself. The items are just "prestigious".

> Buying them gives you the item itself plus a unique skin for it,
>   skipping any progression required to unlock them.

Comment: ACG goes into depth of currencies.  I watched it last night and can't really remember exactly what he said.  Something about doing side missions to earn the special currency to get those prestigious pieces.  You can also buy that currency with real world money.  Not a bad review either.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XhyvG2bluik